How do you pass a foreign key value and automatically select it in a django form, Instead of a user having to auto select the value on the dropdown
`I want to create a dropdown to automatically detect and hold a value of a foreign key in my django form. When I try to create an Address for a soldier, I want that particular soldier to automatically be selected in the drop down field so that the user doesn't have to select the soldier from the dropdown values manually.
Below is my models.py file

from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Soldier(models.Model):
    army_no = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    full_names = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    formal_educ = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    courses_attnd = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    appointment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='soldiers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_names

class Address(models.Model):
    district = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sub_county = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    parish = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    vilage = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    soldier = models.ForeignKey(Soldier,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.district

